# Barcode for each group product or for each product

Tags: barcode

I have to develop software for shop. When getting product detail while billing I have to use a bar code reader.

My question is regarding the bar code. Should I take a unique bar code for each item or should I take a unique bar code for a group of items

For example, if I have 200 units of Nexus 7 and 300 units of Samsung Galaxy S4. Should I take One bar code for Nexus 7 and another for Galaxy S4 or should I take one bar code for each piece?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how these products will be physically handled, but I think you want to use packages or handling units. For example if 100 Nexus 7 products will fit into the container you use for them, but only 50 Galaxy S4's will fit into the boxes used for them, you will need 2 packages of N7's but 6 for S4's.

Establish a unique handling unit identifier for each box and place a barcode label on it that contains barcodes for the package ID and invoice or PO number. Those two numbers should be sufficient to let a system know what is in the box, but you may also include a barcode for quantity and part number on the package label.

If all these products are placed in a non-segregated container, then you have a mixed-lot, and the quantity should be stored in a system, but you should have a label for each unique SKU in the container with it's quantity for that container. The mixed lot container should also have its own label with the package identifier and a invoice or PO number.

The system needs to be able to read the package label to determine what's in the box.